# How to select grouped rows with only NULL values?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

If I have a table like

```
task_id | state
--------+------------ 
   1    |  NULL
--------+------------
   1    |  RESOLVED
--------+------------
   2    |  NULL
--------+------------
   2    |  NULL
```

How can I get grouped rows via task_id which state is only NULL. In this case only rows with task_id 2.

Comment: Do you want just the task_id 2, or the two rows with task_id = 2?

Comment: What do you thik if I write groped row via task_id?

Comment: I think groping's thik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING` to return task_id having only null states.

```
select task_id
from tablename
group by task_id
having max(state) is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
SELECT task_id
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE state NOT IN (SELECT task_id
                    FROM YOUR_TABLE
                    WHERE task_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite it to joins instead of subselect?

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 1):

here is my approach :

```
    Select  * from yourTable where state is null and task_id not in 
    (select task_id from yourTable y where state is not null )
```

Comment: I think this will not return only task_id = 2

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite it to joins instead of subselect?

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

As `COUNT` function ignores `NULL` in case a specific column is assigned, you can use `group by`, `count` and `having` as below.

```
SELECT task_id
FROM t1
GROUP BY task_id
HAVING count(STATE) = 0;
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/FOF56137)**